# VB 2010 : Add items in first menustrip

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

i want to add a new toolstripmenuitem, but at the first/beginning of menustrip

[image]

item "a" named from visual design and item "1" named from code (as new toolstripmenuitem)

how to put item "1" at the beginning / first position of menustrip ?

thanks :) (sorry for my english :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to Add an item at position you need to use `Insert` as in

```
ts.Items.Insert (0, item)
```

And please, don't call everything "item" and "subitem".